# jQuery: get input selection range

Tags: jquery

Is there any event in jQuery to listen to input selections?

For example, let's say I've written `foo_bar` in a text input. I then select the word foo with the mouse. So the event should return `0, 2` (the string position of `foo`).

Is there any possible way to accomplish this? I don't know where to start, I'm flipping trought jQuery API pages but can't seems to find anything helpfull.

I though about listening to `mousedown` events on the input, then somehow retrieve the position of the string where the click happened (not sure if it's even possible) and then getting the position where the `mouseup` happened.

Any info, sources or examples will be welcomed.

Comment: @Anujith the link not work (404 Not Found)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
$('#foo').select(function(e) {
    var start = e.target.selectionStart;
    var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
    console.log('Changed: ' + start + ' to ' + end);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZyDjV/1/

---

You can use the **select** event for this:

```
$('#foo').select(function(e) {
   console.log('Selection Changed');
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyDjV/

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the selected text or its positions? I'm inspecting the object it returned but doesn't seems to store anything

Comment: Great and very clean. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/rT5vR/

```
var getSelected = function(){
var t = '';
if(window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
} else if(document.getSelection) {
    t = document.getSelection();
} else if(document.selection) {
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return t;
}

$("#myElement").select(function(eventObject) {
alert(getSelected().toString());
});
```

​

Comment: great, It's a cleaner implementation of the code at the webpage you posted. I'll try it now. BTW, how much cross-browser is this?