# Find selected text in textarea with Angular Material 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

How do you find the selected text in a `textarea` in an [Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2) input component? I need to create a directive for it.

Comment: "I need to create a directive for it."

Is it a question?

Comment: You need `someString.indexOf(substring)` :)

Comment: And what does the directive have to do? string indexOf already does what you want.

Comment: edit title and post for clarity and brevity, add Angular Material link

Answer (score 4):

Handle the [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) event of your input:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi" (select)="selectionchange($event)">
</md-input-container>
```

Then, use the approach from the [jQuery: get input selection range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855054/jquery-get-input-selection-range) thread to get the selected text:

```
selectionchange(ev:any) {
  const start = ev.target.selectionStart;
  const end = ev.target.selectionEnd;
  console.log(ev.target.value.substr(start, end - start))
}
```

See the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ITAZ4LeYXydKiaciTu4W?p=preview) that illustrates this.

Comment: your plunkr is broken